# Convert a single character to a string?

Tags: c++, character

Simple question (in C++):

How do I convert a single character into a string.
So for example, I have `string str = "abc";`

And I want to extract the first letter, but I want it to be a string as opposed to a character.

I tried

```
string firstLetter = str[0] + "";
```

and

```
string firstLetter = & str[0];
```

Neither works. Ideas?

Comment: A subset of [casting - C++ convert from 1 char to string? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201590/c-convert-from-1-char-to-string) (this is a special case where the char comes from an existing std::string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preferred conversion from char (not char\*) to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728699/preferred-conversion-from-char-not-char-to-stdstring)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Off the top of my head, if you're using STL then do this:

```
string firstLetter(1,str[0]);
```

Comment: Note that `std::string` is not from that part of the standard library that was derived from the STL.

Comment: Adding this comment to clear up what the syntax indicates. This basically says, _**"I want a `string` named `firstLetter` that grabs `1` character starting from `str`'s first (`[0]`) element."**_ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck - actually it doesn't. It says "give me 1 copy of the given character". It can't "start" from the first element of `str`, because `str` isn't even passed, rather the character at `str[0]` is passed by value. If you use 2 instead of 1 you'll get two copies of the first character, _not_ the first two characters. That's directly from your link where you can see it's form (2) of the constructor, documented as: _2) Constructs the string with count copies of character ch. The behavior is undefined if count >= npos._

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `std::string(size_t , char )` constructor:

```
string firstletter( 1, str[0]);
```

or you could use `string::substr()`:

```
string firstletter2( str.substr(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 6):

1)  Using [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)

```
  std::string str="abc",r;
  std::stringstream s;
  s<<str[0];
  s>>r;
  std::cout<<r;
```

2)   Using `string ( size_t n, char c );` [`constructor`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

```
  std::string str="abc";
  string r(1, str[0]);
```

3)   Using [`substr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

```
  string r(str.substr(0, 1));
```

Comment: Also, this will work, too: `string r(&str[0], 1);` or `string r(str.c_str(), 1);`

Answer (score 4):

```
string s;
char a='c';
s+=a; //now s is "c"
```

or

```
char a='c';
string s(1, a); //now s is "c"
```

Comment: I think my solution is correct, don't know why I got a -1.

Comment: `std::string` does not have a constructor that accepts a single `char` as input by itself, so `string s(a);` will not work.  However, `string s(1, a);` and `string s(&a, 1);` will work instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use `string::substr`.

In the example below, `f` will be the string containing 1 characters after offset 0 in `foo` (in other words, the first character).

```
string foo = "foo";
string f = foo.substr(0, 1);

cout << foo << endl; // "foo"
cout << f << endl; // "f"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char characterVariable = 'z';
string cToS(1, characterVariable);

//cToS is now a string with the value of "z"
```

Answer (score 2):

string firstletter(str.begin(), str.begin() + 1);

Answer (score 0):

you can try this it works

```
string s="hello";

string s1="";

s1=s1+s[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to **return a string**, there 2 ways to do this is given below:

1.`return (string) "" + S[i];

2.`string s.push_back(originals[k];return s;`