# C++: insert char to a string

Tags: c++, string, insert, stringstream

so I am trying to insert the character, which i got from a string, to another string.
Here I my actions:
 1. I want to use simple:

```
someString.insert(somePosition, myChar);
```

2. I got an error, because insert requires(in my case) char* or string
3. I am converting char to char* via stringstream:

```
stringstream conversion;
char* myCharInsert;
conversion << myChar //That is actually someAnotherString.at(someOtherPosition) if that matters;
conversion >> myCharInsert;
someString.insert(somePosition, myCharInsert);
```

4. Everything seems to be compiling successfully, but program crashes the gets to

```
conversion >> myCharInsert;
```

line.

5.I am trying to replace char* with string:

```
stringstream conversion;
char* myCharInsert;
conversion << myChar //That is actually someAnotherString.at(someOtherPosition) if that matters;
conversion >> myCharInsert;
someString.insert(somePosition, myCharInsert);
```

Everything seems to be OK, but when `someAnotherString.at(someOtherPosition)` becomes space, program crashes.

So how do I correctly do this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are a number of overloads of [`std::string::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert).  The overload for inserting a single character actually has three parameters:

```
string& insert(size_type pos, size_type n, char c);
```

The second parameter, `n`, is the number of times to insert `c` into the string at position `pos` (i.e., the number of times to repeat the character.  If you only want to insert one instance of the character, simply pass it one, e.g.,

```
someString.insert(somePosition, 1, myChar);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest is to provide yourself with a function that turns a character into a string. There are lots of ways of doing this, such as

```
string ToStr( char c ) {
   return string( 1, c );
}
```

Then you can simply say:

```
someString.insert(somePosition, ToStr(myChar) );
```

and use the function in other cases where you want a string but have a char.

Answer (score 1):

> 4. Everything seems to be compiling successfully, but program crashes the gets to

```
conversion >> myCharInsert;
```

The problem is that you are trying to dereference(access) `myCharInsert`(declared as a `char*` ) which is pointing to a random location in memory(which might not be inside the user's address space) and doing so is Undefined Behavior (crash on most implementations).

**EDIT**

To insert a `char` into a string use `string& insert ( size_t pos1, size_t n, char c );` [overload](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/).

**Extra**

To convert `char` into a `std::string` read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222572/convert-a-single-character-to-a-string/3222605#3222605) answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
std::string someString{"abc"};
someString.push_back('d');
```