# str.insert doesn't work in VS (c++)

Tags: c++, string

```
int a=sizeof(out);
int b=sizeof(s2);
out+=s2;
out.insert(a,(70-a-b)," ");
```

out and s2 are strings. I want to add some space characters between the two strings and make the total length 70. VS wants "const char *" for the second parameter. I've read [C++: insert char to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223302/c-insert-char-to-a-string) but I still don't know how to modify my code given above.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> out and s2 are strings. I want to add some space characters between
>   the two strings and make the total length 70.

First of all, sizeof is the wrong operator here. You need

```
int a = out.size();
int b = s2.size() ;
```

One option to do what you want is

```
int spaceCount = 70-a-b;
out += string(spaceCount, ' ') + s2;
```

Another option is to use setw:

```
ostringstream resultSS;
resultSS << out << setw(70-out.size()) << right << s2;
out = resultSS.str();
```

Comment: Where does the `ostringstream` suddenly come from?  (For the rest, you definitely should check that `spaceCount` is not negative before passing it to the constructor of `string`.  Because of the signed to unsigned conversion, a negative value will _not_ behave as one might reasonably expect.)

Comment: I took the first method, but it seems spaceCount would take negative values in my code and VS gives "Invalid allocation size: 4294967295 bytes". so I add this line: int spaceCount = 70-a-b;
 if(spaceCount>0){spaceCount=spaceCount;}
 else{spaceCount=1;}

Comment: @tsinghsia You didn't mention before that you wanted at least 1 blank.  If you're going to call `std::string( spaceCount, ' ' )` anyway, you might as well use `std::max( 1, spaceCount )` as the argument.  (And you certainly don't need the `spaceCount = spaceCount;` in the `if` branch.  Just inverse the test, and drop the else.)

Answer (score 1):

While it shouldn't be too difficult to insert the text in
question, once you've gotten the correct size (using `a.size()`
and `b.size()`), I question whether this is the best solution.
I'd probably append the necessary padding to `out` *before*
appending `s2`.  Something like:

```
int padding = 70 - (asInt( out.size() ) + asInt( s2.size() ) );
if ( padding > 0 ) {
    out.append( padding, ' ' );
}
out.append( s2 );
```

The extra tests are necessary because `std::string` uses an
unsigned type (`size_t`) for the size, and unsigned types in C++
tend to lead to some surprizing results.  (The `asInt` may or
may not be necessary, depending on where the strings come from.
They're basically:

```
int
asInt( size_t original )
{
    if ( original > std::numeric_limits<int>::max() ) {
        throw std::range_error( "size too large for int" );
    return static_cast<int>( original );
}
```

In many cases, you will know that the strings cannot be too long
before you get to this point in the code, and so you don't need
them.

Note that you *must* convert the sizes to `int` (or some other
signed type) before calculating the padding.  Otherwise, the
calculation will give the wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/).

Just correct the last instruction by this:

```
out.insert(a," ",(70-a-b<70)?(70-a-b):70);
```

Comment: That's not really sufficient.  What happens if `a` is 60 and `b` is 11?

Comment: That's a clever fix.  But why didn't you just use `std::max( 70 - (a + b), 0 )`.

Comment: you're right :), but I think std::max(70-(a-b), 70) not 0 in stead of 70