# Insert a char from vector to string in c++

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

I want to insert a char which saved into a vector, to a string variable.

I'm using this code but I have get error:

```
result.insert(result.size(), G1[fromPos]);
```

in this code, G1 is a vector with char type and result is a string variable.

But I get this error:

> no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits,
>   _Alloc>::insert [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list argument types are: (size_t, char)

What I have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: possible [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223302/c-insert-char-to-a-string) ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use `result.size()` as an index where a char should be placed, as it will result in a `std::out_of_range` exception:

> *If this (pos) is greater than the object's length, it throws out_of_range.*

Secondly, according to the [std::string::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/) specification, to insert a single char you should use the following overload:

```
result.insert(index, 1, G1[fromPos]);
```

The best solution, if you want to append a single char to the **end** of a string, is to use:

```
result.push_back(G1[fromPos]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to append a char to a string, you can use the += operator.