# Insert characters between a string

Tags: c++, string

I am faced with a simple yet complex challenge today.

In my program, I wish to insert a `-` character every three characters of a string. How would this be accomplished? Thank you for your help.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "thisisateststring";

    // Desired output: thi-sis-ate-sts-tri-ng
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did that work? How didn't that work? And please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please attempt a solution before posting the question.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy Before creating this post I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223302/c-insert-char-to-a-string), but I am unsure of how to implement this into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just take an empty string and append "-"  at every count divisible by 3

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "thisisateststring";
    std::string res="";
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        count++;
        res+=s[i];
        if(count%3==0){
            res+="-";
        }
    }
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
thi-sis-ate-sts-tri-ng
```

Comment: This code does work the way I wish it to! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to "build a new string".

Loop a position iteration, starting at `3`, incrementing by **`4`** with each pass, inserting a `-` at the position indicated. Stop when the next insertion point would breach the string (which has been growing by one with each pass, thus the need for the `4` slot skip):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "thisisateststring";

    for (std::string::size_type i=3; i<s.size(); i+=4)
        s.insert(i, 1, '-');

    // Desired output: thi-sis-ate-sts-tri-ng
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
thi-sis-ate-sts-tri-ng
```

Comment: `insert()` scales pretty badly - you'll end up copying _O(n²)_ characters, for a _n_-character string.

Comment: @Toby Speight For most common string sizes that's probably irrelevant. Much more important is the fact that it's a simple and readable solution.

Answer (score 1):

A general (and efficient) approach is to build a new string by iterating character-by-character over the existing one, making any desired changes as you go. In this case, every third character you can insert a hyphen:

```
std::string result;
result.reserve(s.size() + s.size() / 3);
for (size_t i = 0; i != s.size(); ++i) {
    if (i != 0 && i % 3 == 0)
        result.push_back('-');
    result.push_back(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: as index starts from 0 so first append will happen at 4 the place

Comment: @Roushan45: Nope. The hyphen is inserted just before the 4th character, not after. This is done so that if the string length is a multiple of three a trailing hyphen won't be inserted.

Comment: mean to say when tha value of i wil be 3 then it will go inside the if but its already at index 4 of string

Comment: When `i` is 3, the `if` will indeed be entered, but the 4th character (at `s[i]`) *has not been inserted yet*.

Comment: got it, i debug it how actually flow works, and works :), sorry for any trouble

Comment: @Roushan45: No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Iterate the string and build a new one

Copy each character from the old string to the new one and every time you've copied 3 characters add an extra '-' to the end of the new string and restart your count of copied characters.

Answer (score 0):

Like 99% problems with text, this one can be solved with a [regular expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) one-liner:

```cpp
std::regex_replace(input, std::regex{".{3}"}, "$&-")
```

However, it brings not one, but two new problems:

- it is not a very performant solution
- regex library is huge and bloats resulting binary

So think twice.

Comment: Although I actually think [regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) are fabulous, I find this Jamie Zawinski quip funny:  Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple functor to add the hyphens, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct inserter
{
    unsigned n = 0u;
    void operator()(char c)
    {
        std::cout << c;
        if (++n%3 == 0) std::cout << '-';
    }
};
```

This can be passed to the standard `for_each()` algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "thisisateststring";
    std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), inserter());
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Exercise: extend this class to work with different intervals, output streams, replacement characters and string types (narrow or wide).