# Preferred conversion from char (not char*) to std::string

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion

I have a `char`, a plain old character, that I would like to turn into an `std::string`.  `std::string(char)` doesn't exist of course.  I could create a char array and copy it in, I could go through string streams, or many other little roundabout routes.  Currently, I prefer `boost::lexical_cast`, but even that seems too verbose for this simple task.  So what's the preferred way?