# Passing the value of char into string to be used for comparing

Tags: c++, arduino, gsm

I am working on a project which will I use Arduino (ATMEGA328) and a GSM (SIM900).

The received messages are stored in a `inchar`. I was able to print the value of `inchar` on serial monitor but I want to find a specific word inside the `inchar`.

Is there any way to pass that char to string so i can use the substring function of string?

Please help. Here's the snippet of my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
#include <string.h>

char inchar; // Will hold the incoming character from the GSM shield

SoftwareSerial SIM900(2, 3);
//String inchar1;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // wake up the GSM shield
  SIM900power(); 
  SIM900.begin(9600);
  delay(20000);
  SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(100);
  SIM900.print("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0\r"); 
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Ready....");
}

void SIM900power()
{
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  delay(7000);
}

 void loop() 
{

if(SIM900.available() >0)
  {
    inchar=SIM900.read();
    Serial.print(inchar);


}
}
```

Here is the output in Serial Monitor:

```
+CMT: "+1234567890","","15/01/13,10:51:29+32"
amessage deleted!
```

I want to compare the `+1234567890` only and discard the others. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728699/preferred-conversion-from-char-not-char-to-stdstring

Comment: @Jonny Henly The inchar holds ALL the values that outputed in the Serial Monitor. If i declare string s(1, inchar); after the SIM900.read();, nothing happens.

Comment: @Jonny Henly class String has no member named push_back. It says. I am using Arduino IDE.

Comment: @Jonny Henly Yes. I'm into java. But when I tried lowercase, the IDE does not know that, thus redirecting me to use String instead of string. Iam using Arduino IDE.

Comment: @Vonne oh my mistake, I got IDE confused with API for some reason.

Comment: @Vonne Add `String s = "";` under `char inchar;` next add either `s += inchar;` or `s.concat(inchar);` under `inchar=SIM900.read();`. [Here is a link](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) to the Arduino `String` object reference. It also has examples using substrings and comparisons.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I tried to print the value of s, and it prints like infinity. It does not stop. Not a solution. I'm losing hope...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a `String` Class instead of an array. See here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject

`yourString.index(",")` will allow you to locate the first occurence of a ",".

Then you will be able to cut your String using `yourString.substring(start, stop)`.