# C++ converting char variable to string variable is returning ASCII value

Tags: c++

My function looks like this:

```
string toOriginal(char c)
{
    if (c == '$')
        return "car";
    else if (c == '#')
        return "cdr";
    else if (c == '@')
        return "cons";
    else
    {
        string t = to_string(c);
        return t;
    }
}
```

However, when my character c contains a value like 'r', I would like for it to return "r" as a string. However, it returns a string "114".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::to_string` does not have an overload that takes a `char`. It converts the `char` to an `int` and gives you the string representation of the `int`.

Use `std::string`'s constructor.

```
string t(1, c);
```

Comment: Your arguments need to be switched: e.g. string t(1, c);
Other than that, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @nhershy, aah. Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use alternative string constructor like this:

```
  ...
    else
    {
        return std::string(&c, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `to_string()` is for [converting a numerical value to a string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/). A `char` is a numerical type.

See this related question on how to do it right: [Preferred conversion from char (not char*) to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728699/preferred-conversion-from-char-not-char-to-stdstring)