# How can I create a string from a single character?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, char

I have a single `char` value, and I need to cast/convert it to a `std::string`. How can I do this?

I know how to go the opposite way, to retrieve a `char` from a `std::string` object: you just need to index the string at the appropriate location. For example: `str[0]` will retrieve the first character in the string.

But how do I go the other way? I want something like:

```
char c = 34;
std::string s(c);
```

…but this doesn't work (the string is always empty).

Answer (score 259, accepted):

You can use any/all of the following to create a `std::string` from a single character:

- ```
  std::string s(1, c);

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  ```
- ```
  std::string s{c};

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  ```
- ```
  std::string s;
  s.push_back(c);

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  ```

Comment: The shortest way is:  `string s = string() + 'a'`;

Comment: @doctorram a shorter way is `string s = {c};` or `string s({c});` or `string s{c};` https://ideone.com/eFZTFY

Comment: I think @RemyLebeau's solution works best when you have to create a string and pass it as an argument to a function in just one line

Comment: @doctorram 's method also works for multiple characters, as it works with string literals like `const char*`.

Answer (score 101):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes a number and a character.  The character will repeat for the given number of times.  Thus, you should use:

```
std::string str(1, ch);
```

Comment: This is the right answer. But what I don't like about this constructor is that I don't use it enough to remember the order of the parameters. And if you get them switched, it still compiles.

Comment: @Fred Larson This is of course what just happened to me as I was trying this solution.

Comment: It only works for the case of one char though. What if you have `char x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }`? )

Comment: For an array of chars, @Maxim, use the constructor that takes a pointer and the number of chars. In your case, `std::string(x, 3)`.

Comment: @Rob: but that is another constructor, I was referring to the limitation of the fill constructor. You could do as well `std::string(&ch, 1)`.

Comment: Well, yeah, @Maxim. The class provides multiple constructors. My point is that we should use the right one for the job.

Comment: @Fred: std::string is an implementation kitchen-sink all around; however, it helps to remember that all sequences have a constructor taking a count and value parameter, with the value defaulted to T().

Comment: Horrible order of parameters. And why not just allow one char and no count parameter?

Comment: Lack of char constructor also means lack of conversion.  So, e.g., while you can pass a `char*` to a function that takes `const std::string` argument, you can't pass a `char` -- which seems unnecessarily limiting.

Comment: Dang I meant `const std::string&`.

Answer (score 12):

You can try stringstream. An example is below:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::stringstream ss;
std::string target;
char mychar = 'a';
ss << mychar;
ss >> target;
```

Comment: This solution works, however using stringstream (`<sstream>`) is not necessary since it will include the whole library in the project, slowing down the compilation process. Try to avoid including unnecessary dependencies to your project.

Comment: I would argue that that is an over-complex rather than "easy" solution.  That said the problem itself may be an over-simplification and using a string stream might be appropriate in other cases (where other types are to be inserted into the string).

Answer (score 11):

This solution will work regardless of the number of `char` variables you have:

```
char c1 = 'z';
char c2 = 'w';
std::string s1{c1};
std::string s12{c1, c2};
```

Answer (score 4):

You still can use the string constructor taking two iterators:

```
char c = 'x';
std::string(&c, &c + 1);
```

**Update:**

Good question James and GMan. Just searched freely downloadable "The New C Standard" by Derek M. Jones for "pointer past" and my first hit was:

> If the expression P points to an
> element of an array object and the
> expression Q points to the last
> element of the same array object, the
> pointer expression Q+1 compares
> greater than P... even though Q+1 does
> not point to an element of the array
> object...
>
> On segmented architectures
> incrementing a pointer past the end of
> a segment causes the address to wrap
> segmented architecture around to the
> beginning of that segment (usually
> address zero). If an array is
> allocated within such a segment,
> either the implementation must ensure
> that there is room after the array for
> there to be a one past the end
> address, or it uses some other
> implementation technique to handle
> this case (e.g., if the segment used
> is part of a pointer’s representation,
> a special one past the end segment
> value might be assigned)...
>
> The C relational operator model enables
> pointers to objects to be treated in
> the same way as indexes into array
> objects. Relational comparisons
> between indexes into two different
> array objects (that are not both
> subobjects of a larger object) rarely
> have any meaning and the standard does
> not define such support for pointers.
> Some applications do need to make use
> of information on the relative
> locations of different objects in
> storage. However, this usage was not
> considered to be of sufficient general
> utility for the Committee to specify a
> model defining the behavior...
>
> Most implementations perform no checks
> prior to any operation on values
> having pointer type. Most processors
> use the same instructions for
> performing relational comparisons
> involving pointer types as they use
> for arithmetic types. For processors
> that use a segmented memory
> architecture, a pointer value is often
> represented using two components, a
> segment number and an offset within
> that segment. A consequence of this
> representation is that there are many
> benefits in allocating storage for
> objects such that it fits within a
> single segment (i.e., storage for an
> object does not span a segment
> boundary). One benefit is an
> optimization involving the generated
> machine code for some of the
> relational operators, which only needs
> to check the segment offset component.
> This can lead to the situation where
> p >= q is false but p > q is true,
> when p and q point to different objects.

Comment: Is this strictly valid?  Can you treat a scalar object as a one-element array and then use the one-past-the-end pointer?

Comment: Absolutely. An array of one element and a scalar have the same layout and alignment. In fact, sizeof(element) is defined as a multiple of element's alignment, so that there is no padding between the elements of an array.

Comment: @Maxim: How do we know that? A pointer one past the end of an array is valid (though cannot be dereferenced), but I don't think a pointer one past an element is, like @James says.

Comment: @GMan: we know it because it is common knowledge. Why could not be an object treated like a one element array?

Comment: @Maxim: An appeal to common knowledge is the same as "because I think so, I hope so, and it should be"; that doesn't make it so. No, it's not "common knowledge" or James and I wouldn't be asking. I really doubt that this answer has defined behavior.

Comment: §5.7/4 "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one" It's OK.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Your first sentence should rather read: "You still can use the string constructor taking two *pointers*:"

Answer (score 3):

This works on gcc C++ 4.9.2 (http://ideone.com/f3qhTe)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::string test;

    test = (char) 76;
    test += (char) 77;
    test += (char) 78;
    test += (char) 79;

    std::cout << "test contains: " << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In most cases you can just use `{ch}`.

```
std::string s = {ch}; // works
infix.push({ch}); // works
```

This utilises the [std::initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) constructor of `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java that much, but the closest in C++ to your `ch + ""` is probably `std::string{} + ch`. Note, that `""` is not a `std::string`, and you cannot overload operators for fundamental types, hence `ch+""` cannot possibly result in a `std::string`.

However, `std::string{} + ch` involves 2 strings. I suppose the temporary can be optimized away by the compiler, though to construct a string from one character this is perfectly fine: `std::string(1,ch)`.

For other constructors of `std::string` I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a string equal to a char.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string s;
   char one = '1';
   char two = '2';
   s = one;
   s += two;
   cout << s << endl;
}
```

> ./test
> 12