# Setting std::string to 0 during definition vs setting std::string to 0

Tags: c++, string, constructor

I was working on one my projects, and while I was making the constructor for a class, I was setting some of my variables to a default value. I went to set an `std::string` to `NULL`, and it gave me an error. But when I define an `std::string` and set it to `NULL` on the same line, it works without any errors. I was wondering why

**First Example**

```
std::string text = NULL;
```

worked, and

**Second Example**

```
std::string text;
text = NULL;
```

didn't work. Now I know you shouldn't set a string to NULL, or 0, but I found this on accident.

Does the first example call a constructor that takes a `char*`, and thinking that 0 is a pointer to a char? I thought `=` called a constructor too, so I don't get why they wouldn't both work, unless `std::string` specifically overloads the `=` operator.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: Aren't you getting run-time error, at line `std::string text = NULL;`?

Comment: @mnciitbhu nope, I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express. No errors at all.

Comment: @mnciitbhu so there's apparently some sort of discrepancy between the two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value of [`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) evaluates to `0`.

Now, `std::string text = NULL;` will call constructor taking `const char*` and try to copy the data, but since [`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) doesn't point to anything, an error will occur at run-time, I am getting (with gcc 5.2) :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

Since, there is no `operator=` defined for `std::string` and `int`(or `size_t`), `text = NULL;` will not compile.

Comment: But doesn't the `=` call the `size_t` ctor again?

Comment: @GregM It calls the assignment operator. It's a bit confusing but using operator= in the context of initialization invokes an implicit constructor, while doing it post-initialization invokes an assignment operator.

Comment: @Ike @Ike I thought this, so I tested it out. I made a class `Test` and had a constructor take an int. When I did `Test t = 5`, it called the constructor, and `t = 10` also called the ctor. Wouldn't `t = 10` call the assignment operator?

Comment: It does, but where it gets hairy is implicit construction. For example, if you have implicit: `Foo(int x)`, and no overloaded assignment operator for int, then trying to do: `Foo f; f = 123;` ... will actually call the parameterized constructor for Foo to implicitly construct it, and then the implicitly-generated assignment `Foo& operator=(const Foo&);`

Comment: So in those kinds of cases, it's first constructing `Foo` from 123 (implicitly behind your back), and then calling the copy assignment operator for `const Foo&`. In that kind of case with an implicit constructor and no overloaded `operator=` for the operand type, it's calling *both* the constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: @Ike so it's creating a temporary Foo and copying it? Kind of like doing `Foo f = Foo (123);`?

Comment: @GregM: Basically, yes. Performance-wise, the compiler can do shortcuts as long as the semantics don't change (i.e. creating the "temporary" in-place, or -- since C++11 -- move-constructing it.) The idea is, since there is no way to *assign* an `int` to `Foo`, the compiler looks for alternatives, and finds that it's possible to assign a `Foo` to `Foo` *and* possible to *construct* a `Foo` from `int`, so that's what it does.

Comment: @GregM you can check if copy constructor is also used by deleting copy constructor, and checking if there are any errors. See http://ideone.com/nLke48

Comment: `Since, there is no operator= defined for std::string and int` not actually true, it not compiled because of there are two possible `operator=` `operator=(char)` and `operator=(const char *)`

Comment: @0x6773 "*since NULL doesn't point to anything, an error will occur at run-time*" - that is not guaranteed. Technically, passing `NULL` to the `std::string` constructor is *undefined behavior*, so anything could happen, including a crash

Answer (score 1):

The reason the 2nd assignment

```
text = NULL;
```

is in the VC++ compiler error message. It says:

> error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
> could be 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator> &std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>::operator =(const _Elem)'
> or       'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator> &std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>::operator =(const _Elem *const )'

Breaking it down a bit, that says:

> error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
> could be 'std::string &std::string::operator =(const char)'
> or       'std::string &std::string::operator =(const char *const )'

So it doesn't work is because the compiler isn't sure whether `0` is meant to be a `char` value, or `const char*`.

It will compile if you use single quotes around the `0` to turn it into a `char` value:

```
text = '\0'; // NULL or can use any other character
```

Or if you cast it to a pointer type

```
type = (const char*)NULL; // Crashes, but now we're sure what type 0 is meant to be
```

that would compile also. Keep in mind assigning the `std::string` to a `NULL` pointer will crash as it tries to copy characters from `NULL`.

Comment: Along those lines, the reason the 1st constructor works is because there is no constructor that takes a single `char`, but there is one that takes a `const char*`, so passing `NULL` to the constructor is not ambiguous (just *undefined behavior*).

Comment: Yes, the `std::string` [fill constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728725/) that accepts `char` also requires an `int` argument, for how many of that `char` to use (it is `std::string(int, char)`