# Copy constructor not being called, trouble understanding how the assignment operator works

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I couldn't really think of a specific title, as I don't really know how to word it. I'm really confused on this, as my previous question did not really get answered, but only make me more confused. My other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706112/setting-stdstring-to-0-during-definition-vs-setting-stdstring-to-0) asked

> Setting std::string to 0 during definition vs setting std::string to 0

User [mnciitbhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3789604/mnciitbhu) said that he was getting an error on GCC 5.2. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio so I tried it on Code::Blocks, and there were no errors. Besides that, I wanted to try this out for myself. I have a class - `Test`

```
class Test {

public:

    Test(const Test& T) {

        std::cout << "COPY CTOR\n";

    }

    Test(){

        std::cout << "DEFAULT CTOR\n";

    }

    Test(int NUMBER) {

        std::cout << "INT CTOR CALLED\n";

    }


};
```

Inside my main function, when I do

```
Test t1 = 5;
t1 = 10;
```

the output is

`INT CTOR CALLED`

`INT CTOR CALLED`

Now where I am getting confused is when you do `Test t1 = 5`, a user on the other question said it will create a temporary `Test`, then call the copy constructor. This never calls the copy constructor. Also, in reference to my other question; when I did

```
 // text = std::string
 text = NULL;
```

one of the answers said that it didn't work because it did not define `operator=`. My `Test` class never defined it either, but doing

```
t1 = 10;
```

still works and calls the constructor again. One of the users on the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706112/setting-stdstring-to-0-during-definition-vs-setting-stdstring-to-0#comment55184443_33706201) said that in this context, it call the assignment operator. This did not, as you can tell from the output. So could someone please explain, in great detail, why

```
std::string text = NULL;
text = NULL;
```

gives me an error, and

```
Test t1 = 5;
t1 = 10;
```

works, and doesn't call the copy constructor, and calls the constructor twice.

What is the `=` actually doing? Why does it call the constructor when I do `t1 = 10`

Comment: The output of your example should contains `INT CTOR CALLED` instead of `DEFAULT CTOR`, typo?

Comment: @user1034749 yes thank you, that was a typo

Comment: So, what is your question? if you want to compile time error on you code add `explicit` to your `Test` constructor, like this `explicit Test(int NUMBER)`

Comment: Or you can force compilation of your code with `Test& operator=(const Test&) = delete;` in `Test` definition. `operator=` if not defined generated by compiler it self, in several cases.

Comment: Since you didn't overload the assignment operator, you have no idea whether it's called or not. (And *copy elision* is a legitimate optimisation.)

Comment: Regarding the apparent lack of calls to the copy constructor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: @user1034749 my question is what does the `=` actually do?

Answer (score -3):

Usually NULL is defined as `((void*)0)` and `std::string` has no idea of how to construct strings from void* pointers, std::basic_string simply has no such constructors.

Try

```
std::string text = (const char*)0;
```

instead.

Comment: NULL is defined as integer in c++, not a pointer. Your definition of NULL is from C.

Comment: `std::string` can be constructed from `const char*`, therefore it can be constructed from `NULL`.

Comment: @Eugene `NULL` is technically implementation defined in C and C++.

Comment: You should never write code that looks like that.

Comment: @NeilKirk

Exactly, and the same apply to `std::string text = NULL`