# Invalid Conversion from char to string

Tags: c++, string, char, stack

In my code, I made a string and I pushed that string to a stack. 
(I don't know if I did it correctly as I am new to C++ and the concept of stacks)
But when I try to top (I think this outputs the first element in the stack) it doesn't work correctly. I get a conversion issue from char to string. Even if I cast it as char it doesn't work correctly.
Is there some way to convert it?
I am trying to get it to out put h.

I keep getting the error :

C:\main.cpp:15:37: error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'char' to 'std::stack >::value_type&& {aka std::basic_string&&}' [-fpermissive]
             nextWord.push(str[i + 1]);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <string.h>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main(){
std::stack<string> nextWord;
string str = "T<h>is is a test";

for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if (str[i + 2] == '>' && str[i] ==  '<'){
        nextWord.push(str[i + 1]);
    }
}
while (!nextWord.empty()) {
    cout << "String: " << nextWord.top();;
}

cout << nextWord.pop() << '>' ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
nextWord.push(str[i + 1]);
```

`str[i + 1]` is a **char**, and you're trying to push it onto a string stack.  Change it to this, and it should work fine:

```
nextWord.push(string(1, str[i + 1]));
```

Comment: I want to output the H between the <>. So I know right now I need a char or a char*

Comment: edited answer, see above.  Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201590/c-convert-from-1-char-to-string

Answer (score 4):

In you code 3 problems:

1. `nextWord.push(str[i+1]);` You try to put char in the stack instead string.
   You need change the type of stack:
           `stack<char> nextWord;`
   or convert char to string before putting in the stack for example:

   ```
       string tmp = "";

       tmp += str[i+1];

       nextWord.push(tmp);
   ```
2. Endless cycle:

   ```
       while (!nextWord.empty()) {
        cout << "String: " << nextWord.top();
       }
   ```

   `stack.top()` - just returns value in the top of the stack

   to pass all the elements you need add calling stack.pop() in the body of      cycle, for example:

   ```
       while (!nextWord.empty()) {
           cout << "String: " << nextWord.top();
           nextWord.pop();
       }
   ```
3. `cout << nextWord.pop() << '>' ;` The return type of the stack.pop() is void. You can not write like this.

Answer (score 1):

stack::pop has return value void. In order to get the value from the stack use top and then call pop.

```
cout << nextWord.top() << ">";
nextWord.pop();
```

When you push strings you need to push the string, not a character i.e.

```
nextWord.push(str);
```

Also `#include <string>` instead of string.h

Comment: I have that there, but I keep getting this error : 
C:\Users\Victor\ClionProjects\Hw7\main.cpp:15:37: error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'char' to 'std::stack<std::basic_string<char> >::value_type&& {aka std::basic_string<char>&&}' [-fpermissive]
             nextWord.push(str[i + 1]);

Comment: I'm sorry about these stupid questions, but where should I include <string> ?

Comment: no question is stupid. instead of `#include <string.h>` write `#include <string>` also it is better to move your `using namespace std` inside your main function. `int main() { using namespace std; ... }`

Comment: Ok thanks. But what I originally wanted to do was output the H inbetween the <> which I know is a char. So is there a way to output the char?

Comment: yep, `cout << nextWord.top()[2] << endl;`