# Weird memory behaviour with array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays

I was in needing of printing a Vigenere square inside a console window for a personal project but I'm experiencing some problems with the print function since it *sneaks* inside *other classes' memory* and prints out strings coming from them.

For those who don't know what is a Vigenere square, here's a [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher#/media/File:Vigen%C3%A8re_square_shading.svg)

Here's my code:

```
static void square() {
    string cipher[27];
    cipher[0] = "  | A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z";
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        string tmp = (char)(i + 'A') + " |";
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            tmp += " " + (char)(((j + i) % 26) + 'A');
        }
        cipher[i + 1] = tmp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) cout << cipher[i] << endl;
}
```

My approach consists in creating each string one by one using a for cycle which incrememts the row's letter ascii value and another for for each of the coloumns shifted by 1. This is the weird output:

[image: Console]

I'm running this code alone but it steals the string `"Invalid Option! Press any key to dismiss."` *from a class that I previously used to create the menu*. I think it's someway how accessing parts of the memory reserved to that class.
What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to figure this out.

Comment: `(char)(i + 'A') + " |";` doesn't concatenate a char and a string literal.

Comment: This might interest you :<<it means "the pointer to some copy of an empty string, advanced by the numeric value of c (which is definitively not what you wanted); >> quoted from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201590/c-convert-from-1-char-to-string  . C++ is not that smart in contrast to VB.NET . It may seems rational to cast a char to string by adding an empty one before it (""+c) but it means something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in those two lines:

```
string tmp = (char)(i + 'A') + " |";

    tmp += " " + (char)(j + i + 'A');
```

The right side of the assignment is evaluated first and only then is the result used to construct the `std::string`. A string literals are typically stored together in some static memory of the program. In the program the literal has value of a pointer pointing to that memory. A single character is basically a number. While the **+** plus operator is used for concatenating things with `std::string`, it behaves differently for pointers and numbers. If you add a `char` to `char*` pointer (or any pointer) it just points the pointer to a different place - in your case to some other string of the program.

To break it down:

- `(char)(i + 'A') + " |"` assume `i = 0` and `" |"` is stored e.g. on `0xabcd1234`:
- `(char)(0 + 65) + (char*)0xabcd1234`
- `(char)65 + (char*)0xabcd1234`
- `(char*)0xabcd1275` - oops, we did not construct a concated string, we created pointer to some random memory!

---

There are many ways you could write the program. The smallest amount of changes would be this:

```
string tmp = (char)(i + 'A') + string(" |");

    tmp += string(" ") + (char)(j + i + 'A');
```

That means - make sure that at least one side of the + operator is actually `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in your code is that you think that by concatenating an empty string with a char will automatically turn into a string ,which is wrong(it means  "the pointer to some copy of an empty string, advanced by the numeric value of c (which is definitively not what you wanted); >> quoted from here:[C++ convert from 1 char to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201590/c-convert-from-1-char-to-string)).

The final code could look like this:

```
void square() {
    string cipher[27];
    cipher[0] = "  | A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z";
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        string tmp="";
        tmp+=(char)(i + 'A');
        tmp+=" |";
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            tmp += " ";
            tmp+=(char)(j + i + 'A');
        }
        cipher[i + 1] = tmp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) cout << cipher[i] << endl;
}
```

The chars are added to the string individually.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `string` and `char` a lot which might not be your intention. Also I have assumed you are using std::string.

Instead of making an array of strings you should use a char array or a string.

Eg,

```
string cipher;
```