# 'string()+char' in C++

Tags: c++, string

My question is inspired from the comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201751/9656249) SO post.

How exactly does `string()+char`, like `string()+'a'` work?  Specifically:

1. Is the `string()` constructor called for a nameless temporary object?
2. What is the `datatype` of this object?
3. Logically, how can I concatenate a `char` to this object to get a `string`?

Comment: 1) How the temporary object get constructed is implementation-defined. 2) `std::string`, of course, what else could it be? 3) The `+` operator already returns a `std::string`. Nothing else needs to be done in order to obtain a `std::string` out of this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `std::string` implementation, a quick look the relevant functions in the C++ reference can help you understand this behaviour.

> 1. Is the `string()` constructor called for a nameless temporary object?
> 2. What is the datatype of this object?

Calling the constructor [`string()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) with no arguments

> Constructs an empty string, with a length of zero characters.

therefore the datatype of the given object will be of type `std::string`.

> 3. Logically, how can I concatenate a char to this object to get a string?

You concatenate as if you would to any string, trough the [`+` operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/), which is overloaded to work with a string object as the left hand side operand, and a character as the right hand one.