# Get value of char variable into a ref class String in C++ (Visual Studio)

Tags: string, class, c++-cli

I'm now writing some codes for a button of my program on Visual Studio 2017. I have a char variable (for example char c = 't'), then I want the button label (which is button.Text) to be modified by changes of c. The button.Text is a ref class String properties.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    char c = 't';
    String^ xyz;

    button1->Text = xyz;
}
```

[In VisualStudio 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtAjz.png)

[In VisualStudio 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R777C.png)

I have tried this solution but it couldn't work because the button.Text properties is a ref string class, not a string class. 
 [C++ convert from 1 char to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201590/c-convert-from-1-char-to-string)

So can you help me for my problem? Thank you!

Comment: Please include code samples as text **within** your question, which will make your question easier to read, makes it indexable and last-not-least one can copy-paste your code to try and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Don't link to your code, post it in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just think my code is short, so I include the photos of it (to show you that Visual Studio says it's a ref class). I have edited my question.

Comment: Use Char instead of char.

Comment: @HansPassant you mean button1->Text = c in which c is Char instead of char? I have tried this way, and couldn't work. Btw thank you for your help even though I get a solution in the below reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with accordance with @HansPassant advice:
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
  Char c = 't';// Remeber Char is managed one 
  button1->Text = gcnew String(c.ToString());
}
  This way you can avoid marshalling and other costly interop operations
  unless you want to use managed and unmanaged code together.
```

Comment: Wow I really appreciate this method. It's a bit simpler, more intuitive and clear. Thank you and this is definitely way I will use for my program!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is 'Overview of Marshalling in C++': https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp?view=vs-2017

For example:

```
#include "msclr/marshal.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;
int main()
{
    char c = 't';
    String^ sref = marshal_as<String^>(&c);
    Console::WriteLine(sref);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: If you have embedded `NULL`s in your string, the result of marshaling the string is not guaranteed. The embedded `NULL`s can cause the string to be truncated or they might be preserved. ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp?view=vs-2017))

Comment: Thank you for your link, quite helpful, and solve me for the problem now!