# Undefined behavior when converting char to std::string c++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, char, undefined-behavior

My program takes in a vector `std::vector<std::string> vector` and a character `char separator` and returns a string with all of the strings added together between the separator character. The concept is: `vector[0] + separator + vector[1] + separator`

**The Code**

```
std::string VectorToString(std::vector<std::string> vector, char separator)
{
    std::string output;
    for(std::string segment : vector)
    {  
        std::string separator_string(&separator);
        output += segment + separator_string;
    }
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vector = {"Hello",  "my",  "beautiful", "people"};
    std::cout << VectorToString(vector, ' ');
}
```

My expected output is `Hello my beautiful people` 
However the output is:

`Hello �����my �����beautiful �����people �����`

What I have found is that something is wrong with the character, specifically its pointer: `std::cout << &separator;` -> `�ƚ��`. However if I do like this: `std::cout << (void*) &separator;` -> `0x7ffee16d35f7`. Though I don't really know what `(void*)` does.

**Question:**

1.What is happening?

2.Why is it happening?

3.How do I fix it?

4.How do I prevent it from happening in future projekts?

Comment: [casting - C++ convert from 1 char to string? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201590/c-convert-from-1-char-to-string)

Comment: ...That doesn't contain explanation on why it's undefined behavior...

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but creating that `separator_string` object every time through the loop wastes time. Create it once, before the loop. Or, even better, don't create it at all. Just append the character to the string: `output += segment; output += separator;`. (Yes, string objects know how to append a single character) And for the loop, create a reference to each string rather than copying: `for (const std::string& segment : vector)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker why should I use a reference instead of copying. Is it faster or are there any other reasons?

Comment: @ViktorSkarve -- it's faster, and uses fewer resources. For simple programs like this one that doesn't really matter, but when you get into more complex programs it can make a big difference, both in speed and in memory usage. It can make the difference between running successfully and running out of memory. In general, it's a good habit to use `const` references rather than copying big things. That's why so many functions take `const std::string&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
std::string separator_string(&separator);
```

tries to construct a string from a 0-terminated C string.

But    `&separator` is not 0-terminated, because it depends on the other bytes of memory following `separator` if there is an 0 byte in there (probably not). So you're getting undefined behavior.

What you can do is to use other constructor:

```
std::string separator_string(1, separator);
```

This one creates a string by repeating `separator` character 1 time.

Comment: So std::string separator_string(&separator); should be used with c-string and not char?

Comment: yeah,because for ex. this one would work: separator_string(" "); because " " is a zero terminated C string.

Comment: +1, I totally didn't see the `&`. Btw, you don't need to construct a string first, `std::string` overloads `operator+` for char too. So `output += segment + separator;` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

By the standard, following:

```cpp
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

means this:

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the **null-terminated** character string pointed to by s. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is undefined if [s, s + Traits::length(s)) is not a valid range.

Therefore, `std::string separator_string(&separator);` causes an Undefined-Behavior because `separator` is not null-terminated.

To prevent this, you might want to use the following overload:

```cpp
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              size_type count,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

like `std::string separator_string(&separator, 1);` or even more simpler (as other answer pointed out) `std::string separator_string(1, separator);`.