# I have a lot of error with .append method in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a problem with .append methon in C++.
This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
char caratteri[] = {"ciao amici"};
string str = "ciao amici";
string token = "";
for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++)
{
    if(str[i+1] == ' '){
        token = "";
    }
    char current_token = str[i];
    token.append(string(current_token));
    i++;
}
}
```

And this is a part of my output:

```
    c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:397:7: note:   no known                             conversion for argument 1 from 'char' to 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:389:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       basic_string(const _Alloc& __a) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:389:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'char' to 'const std::allocator<char>&'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:380:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits   = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       basic_string()
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why have I got this problem? Can I solve it?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: as said in the error you cannot create a string from a char

Comment: `token.append(string(current_token))` -> `token.append(current_token)`.  You need to append the `char`, not a `string`.

Comment: @NathanOliver `token.append(1, current_token)` I suppose? I suggest `token += current_token;`

Comment: `if(str[i+1] == ' ')` -- This is an out-of-bounds access on the last iteration of the loop.  Then you have this within the `for` loop: `i++;` -- Honestly, this is a confusing piece of code.

Comment: Try `string(1, current_token)`.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201590/c-convert-from-1-char-to-string

Comment: Besides this specific error, what are you trying to do? There are multiple issues in the posted code and its ultimate intent isn't really clear.

Comment: *Can I solve it?* -- If what you're trying to do is simply extract each word separated by a space, there are much easier ways to do this.  Here is one: `std::istringstream strm(str); std::string word; while (strm >> word) token += word;`.

Answer (score 1):

You try to create a `std::string` from a `char` here:

```
token.append(
    string(current_token)   // <- this part
);
```

To create a `std::string` from a single `char`, you need to supply how many times you want the `char` repeated:

```
token.append(string(1, current_token));
```

Fortunately, `append` has en overload that lets you do that directly, without creating an intermediate `std::string`:

```
token.append(1, current_token);
```

But the easiest would probably be to use the `operator+=` overload to add a single `char`:

```
token += current_token;
```

---

Note also that this

```
if(str[i+1] == ' ')
```

will access `str[str.length()]` when `i == str.length() - 1`. That is accessing it out of bounds. It will *probably* work anyway because there's a `\0` stored just out of bounds, but I recommend that you fix that logic.