# Selecting a character from a string

Tags: c++

How can I fix the following error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Vorname = "\"John\"\t";
    string Name = Vorname.append("Cena");
    string x = Name[2];
    cout << x;
    return 0;

}
```

**Error**

> Error:  conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits std::allocator<char, char>::value_type' {aka 'char'} to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string'} requested|

My expectation:

```
Output: h
```

Comment: The return type of `Name[2]` is `char`, not `string`. Unless you specifically want a string to do further operations on?

Comment: The `append` call will modify `Vorname` which is probably not what you meant. Use `+` instead.

Comment: [How can I create a string from a single character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201590/how-can-i-create-a-string-from-a-single-character)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a string from a single character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201590/how-can-i-create-a-string-from-a-single-character)

Comment: No, I don't think it does. It isn't clear that OP wanted `x` to be a string instead of `char`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It is quite clear to me. There was no need to reopen the question. Just repeating what has already been explained in an age old question's answers. The answers given in the dupe list can be used to solve OP's problem, hence this question should be closed as such.

Comment: This *must* be a duplicate. It has probably been asked several hundred times before.

Comment: cont' - Though search is [seriously broken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48AOOynnmqU&t=1m10s). Can the newfangled [OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/) do better?

Answer (score 3):

C++ (unlike Python for example) has different types to represent a single character and strings of characters.

If you want `x` to be a single character, change it to

```
char x = Name[2];
```

If you want `x` to be a string containing one character, you can use the [`substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method:

```
std::string x = Name.substr(2, 1);
```

---

Also, as Sash noticed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77473444/7976805), `h` is at the index `3` in your string.

Answer (score 3):

The issue in your code is with the line:

```cpp
string x = Name[2];
```

`Name[2]` returns a `char`, but you are trying to store it in a `std::string` object. To fix this, you can change the type of `x` from `std::string` to `char`:

```cpp
char x = Name[2];
```

Additionally `h` is the 4th character in `Vorname` so you need to use `3` rather than `2`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string Vorname = "\"John\"\t" ;
  std::string Name = Vorname.append("Cena");
  char x = Name[3];
  std::cout << x << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
h
```

Comment: Better say that there is no constructor for `std::string` that takes a `char` instead. Because it's perfectly possible to **assign** a char to a string (there is an overload of the assignment operator for that purpose). It's just impossible to initialize it with a single `char` (except if we use the dedicated constructor that requires a `count` argument alongside).

Answer (score 3):

There is no constructor in the class `std::string` (or `std::basic_string`) that accepts one character as the first argument like

```
string x = Name[2];
```

Instead you could write for example

```
string x( 1, Name[2] );
```

where this constructor will be called

```
basic_string(size_type n, charT c, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

Another approach is to use the constructor that accepts an initializer list. For example

```
string x = { Name[2] };
```

As for your statement

> My expectation:

```
Output : h
```

then the character 'h' is stored in the string `Name` declared like

```
string Vorname = "\"John\"\t" ;
string Name = Vorname.append("Cena") ;
```

at the position `3`. So you need to use this index in declarations of the string `x` like

```
string x = { Name[3] };
```