# Why can't i construct a std::string from a single char in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

make a `std::string` from a `char`. For example, won't compile,

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char c = 'a';
    std::string s(c);
    return 0;
}
```

in g++, i get *this* much error,

```
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:6:20: error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_strin
g<char>::basic_string(char&)'
     std::string s(c);
                    ^
In file included from i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/in
clude/c++/string:52:0,
                 from foo.cpp:1:
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:535:9: note: candidate: template<class _InputIterator> std::__cxx11::bas
ic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(_InputIterator, _InputIterator,
 const _Alloc&)
         basic_string(_InputIterator __beg, _InputIterator __end,
         ^
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:535:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cpp:6:20: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
     std::string s(c);
                    ^
In file included from i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/in
clude/c++/string:52:0,
                 from foo.cpp:1:
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:465:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _All
oc>::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type
, _CharT, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>;
_Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::size_type = unsigned int]
       basic_string(size_type __n, _CharT __c, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
       ^
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:465:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:455:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _All
oc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = s
td::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())
       ^
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:455:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
foo.cpp:6:20: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissi
ve]
     std::string s(c);
                    ^
In file included from i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/in
clude/c++/string:52:0,
                 from foo.cpp:1:
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:445:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _All
oc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Al
loc>::size_type, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<
char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits
, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
       basic_string(const _CharT* __s, size_type __n,
       ^
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:445:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:427:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _All
oc>::basic_string(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, st
d::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::__cxx11::basi
c_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char
; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
       basic_string(const basic_string& __str, size_type __pos,
       ^
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:427:7: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:411:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _All
oc>::basic_string(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, st
d::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::__cxx11::basi
c_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std
::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_
CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]
       basic_string(const basic_string& __str, size_type __pos,
       ^
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:411:7: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:399:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _All
oc>::basic_string(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [w
ith _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<cha
r>]
       basic_string(const basic_string& __str)
       ^
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:399:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'char' to 'const
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:391:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _All
oc>::basic_string(const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits
<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
       basic_string(const _Alloc& __a)
       ^
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:391:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'char' to 'const
std::allocator<char>&'
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:380:7: note: candidate: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _All
oc>::basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Allo
c = std::allocator<char>]
       basic_string()
       ^
i:/Qtandroid/Qt5.7.0/Tools/mingw530_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/basic_s
tring.h:380:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

is there a justification for this constructor missing.

this works but feels wrong,

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char c = 'a';
    std::string s;
    s += c;
    return 0;
}
```

any advice, thanks.

Comment: You may use `std::string s(1, 'a')`.

Comment: Do you want advice or do you want to know why the constructor doesn't exist?

Comment: @juanchopanza likewise.  I'll be curious to see whether anyone attempts to answer the only actual question asked: "is there a justification for this constructor missing". Unless someone has knowledge of the musings from the standard-committee, it may not be answerable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a single character to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222572/convert-a-single-character-to-a-string)

Comment: One issue is that `std::string s(0);` would be ambiguous (`char` or `const char*`?) and introducing a special overload resolution case for "literal `0` that is used as parameter for `string` constructor" is not a pleasant idea.

Comment: @molbdnilo, that is, indeed, a fair point.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's what i'll use. thanks.

Comment: @juanchopanza i'd quite like to know what would go wrong if `string::string(char)` were added to the class. I accept the `0` case as ambigious, but that's already the case for +=

Answer (score 6):

A `string` is not a `char`, so I don't know why you would expect one to be convertible to the other. The former is a collection of the latter. Indeed, the justification is in the reverse direction - you would need justification for such a constructor to exist and there really isn't one. Having an implicit conversion from `char` to `string` would be very, very odd.

If you want a collection of a single element, there are [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) for that:

```
std::string s1(1, c); // (2) create a string composed of 1 repeated character c
std::string s2{c};    // (9) create a string based on this sequence of chars
```

Comment: It's not unreasonable to expect to be able to create a one-character string from a single char. It just doesn't happen to exist.

Comment: doesn't `std::string s2{c};` need to be `std::string s2{{c}};` or do the braces collapse here?

Comment: @NathanOliver No, we're invoking the `initializer_list<char>` constructor.

Comment: Ah, that's right.  It is greedy so it gets interpreted as list initialization with a list of one.

Comment: @Barmar I think it's pretty unreasonable. Would you expect that for other containers? `Foo f; vector<Foo> v = f;`?

Comment: It wouldn't be unreasonable, IMHO. But I think `char` is more of a special case, since they're not as much used on their own than as elements of strings.

Comment: @Barry strings are such a common object, that i would expect to be able to create one from a character - despite the fact that constructing a singleton in other containers might not exist. I haven't seen a good reason why `string::string(char)` shouldn't exist.

Comment: @jkj You *can* create a string from a single char. What you're asking for instead is to allow that conversion implicitly. Strings being common is way insufficient. Again, why do you think you need such a thing given the more generic alternatives that handle this case?

Comment: @Barry Looks like you can't `String(char)` in Java either. Maybe you're right and it shouldn't exist. It seemed to me a no-brainer that you should be able to implicitly make a string from a char, or at least have `explicit string(char)`

Comment: @jkj We basically do. Except it's spelled `string(initializer_list<char>)` and can take more than one char too.

Answer (score 5):

*std::string* has no constructor from a single *char*. You can see all available constructors [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

From the other side `operator+=` [is overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) for a single *char*.

As it is already mentioned, you can use the constructor:

```
basic_string( size_type count, 
              CharT ch, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

to create an `std::string` from a single *char*, like:

```
std::string s(1, 'a');
```

Comment: I think this is thebest way. Although it amazes me that the simple case of `string(c)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
string const s{ 'A' };
```

The rumours that this is not supported, are exaggerations.

Technically this uses the `initializer_list` constructor.

Comment: what if i have `char c` rather than 'A'?

Comment: It's the same type. And the initializers are evaluated at run time if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a bit odd that there is no single-character constructor, but there is a single-character `operator+=`.

You can use the constructor that accepts a character pointer and a copy count:

```
std::string s(&c, 1);
```

Or the constructor that accepts a single character and a repeat count:

```
std::string s(1, c);
```

Or, in C++11 and later, the constructor that accepts a `std::initialization_list`:

```
std::string s{c};
or
std::string s = {c};
```

Comment: what does `string s = {c};` actually do? i mean, is this a better way than `string(1, c)` ?

Comment: See [List Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). `{c}` in this context is a *braced-init-list*, which is represented by the compiler as a [`std::initializer_list<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) wrapping a fixed array containing the single character `c`. `std::string` has a constructor that accepts a `std::initializer_list<char>` as input.