# cpp declaration of string with a char

Tags: c++, string

I am referring to this post on how to create a string from a char in cpp.

[Convert a single character to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222572/convert-a-single-character-to-a-string)

c is a charactor and inputstr is a vector of strings. 
As stated, if I do this

```
string str2(1,c);
inputstr.push_back(str2);
```

it works and inputstr gets a str append to the end but not when I do

```
inputstr.push_back(string str2(1,c));
```

It throws an error: expected primary-expression before ‘strx’
     inputstr.push_back(string strx(1,c));
What does the error mean? is it because cpp does not support in line declaration, I would expect a different error in that case.

Comment: You want `inputstr.push_back(string(1,c));`.

Comment: The error means that this is not valid C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But,

```
inputstr.push_back(string(1, c));
```

should work.

In your example, you are attempting to declare a variable in an invalid place and that is not valid code, so the compilation fails. In this example, you are simply instantiating a `string` object and passing the instance to `push_back()`. You don't need the variable in this case.