# Output ASCII value of character

Tags: c++, ascii

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char x;
    cout << "enter a character:";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "ASCII Value of " << x << "is" << string(x);
    return 0 ;
}
```

the error is

```
main.cpp||In function 'int main()':| 
main.cpp|10|error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'| 
main.cpp|10|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits,_Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: `returb 0 ;` ->  `return 0 ;`

Comment: x isn't a `const char*` or `char*` so why should `std::string(x)` work?

Comment: looks like you want to [create a `std::string` from a single `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3222587/1460794).

Comment: There is no constructor of `std::string` taking a char.

Comment: Please add more description to your question, like what you're trying to do, what the intended output and what output you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::cout << "ASCII Value of " << x << "is" << (int)x;
```

is one way (the cast circumvents the special treatement of a `char` type by the I/O stream library), but this will output your platform's encoded value of the character, which is not *necessarily* ASCII.

A portable solution is much more complex: You'll need to encode the ASCII set in a 128 element array of elements capable of storing a 7 bit unsigned value, and map `x` to a suitable element of that.

Comment: C++ Core Guidelines ES. 49 says, if you have to use a cast, use a named cast. In this case should be a ```static_cast<int>(x)```. Please promote good practices.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk: No, that's dogma, and is unnecessarily obfuscating in this instance. The rules governing the behaviour of a C-style cast in C++ are extremely well specified. What you must not do is to attempt to propagate dogma in editing another answer, unless it is fixing something that is clearly wrong. The correct action in this case is to answer yourself so presenting an alternative to the community. At the time of writing the other answer has `int(x)`, which has its merits.

Comment: Per Your suggestion I created my own answer. You been a veteran programmer, understand exactly what are the implications of  using this syntax. A beginner will not. I believe a correct answer should, promote best practices. My *suggested* edit to your post was created in line with the guidelines of this site in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 approaches to solving this problem:

- Use `to_string`
- Passing the correct value to `cout`
- Using the `std::string` class correctly

The solutions are marked (numbers in comment).

---

### Use `std::to_string`

Since C++11, there is function to convert numbers to a string ([to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)):

```cpp
/*(1)*/        std::cout << std::to_string( x );
```

There is no specialization for a `char` parameter. So the value is implictly converted.

---

### Passing the correct value to `cout`

`cout` would display the value of `char` object as a character.
If we want to output the value of a `char` object, we need to convert it to a type which is output by `cout` as a number instead of a character.

The C++ standard guarantees:

```cpp
1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

So any of those integer types can be used. Usually `int` is selected.

There are 4 conversions that can be used here:

1) [Implicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) - "Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type T1 is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some other type T2;"

```cpp
/*(2)*/        int i = x;
               std::cout << i;
```

2) [Explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) - "Converts between types using a combination of explicit and implicit conversions."

```cpp
/*(3)*/        std::cout << (int)x;

/*(4)*/        std::cout << int(x); // unsigned int(x) - is invalid, 
                                    // has to be a single-word type name
```

3) A named cast.

```cpp
/*(5)*/        std::cout << static_cast<int>(x);
```

4) Use the `T{e}` notation for construction

```cpp
/*(6)*/        std::cout << int{x};
```

> The `T{e}` construction syntax makes it explicit that construction is desired. The `T{e}` construction syntax doesn’t allow narrowing. `T{e}` is the only safe and general expression for constructing a value of type T from an expression e. The casts notations `T(e)` and `(T)e` are neither safe nor general.

About conversions the *C++ Core Guidelines* specifies the following (among others)

- [ES.48: Avoid casts](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es48-avoid-casts)
- [ES.49: If you must use a cast, use a named cast](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-casts-named)
- [ES.64: Use the `T{e}`notation for construction](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es64-use-the-tenotation-for-construction)

In this case I would suggest (3) or (4).

---

### Using the `std::string` class correctly

`string` is a specialization of `basic_string`

```cpp
using string = basic_string<char>;
```

`basic_string` has many [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

There are only 2 constructors, which can take a predefined number of chars;

> `basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`
>
> Constructs the string with count copies of character ch. The behavior is undefined if count >= npos.

```cpp
/*(7)*/        std::string s = std::string( 1, x );
```

> `basic_string( const CharT* s, size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`
>
> Constructs the string with the first count characters of character string pointed to by s. s can contain null characters. The length of the string is count. The behavior is undefined if s does not point at an array of at least count elements of CharT, including the case when s is a null pointer.

```cpp
/*(8)*/        std::string s = std::string( &x, 1 );
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here. Although I feel this doesn't *directly* answer the question, it does so indirectly, and comprehensively.

Comment: @Bathsheba While downvotes are not required to be  accompanied by a reason, these baffling situations will persist.

Comment: I upped it this morning though. It might be an idea to tie the answer back by saying what the OP should have written, and perhaps even include a section on portability?

Comment: @Bathsheba There are 8 proposals of the correct syntax.

Comment: True, but they are a little buried.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char x;
    cout<< "enter a character:";
    cin>>x;
    cout<< "ASCII Value of "<< x<< "is"<< int(x);
    return 0 ;
}
```

> you mean return try this code

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char x;
    cout<< "enter a character:";
    cin>>x;
    cout<< "ASCII Value of "<< x<< "is"<< char(x);
return 0 ;
}
```

> try this its called return

Comment: Did you try this? `char(x)` is a value copy of `x` with the same type.