# ASCII how to convert for numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 string c;
 cout << "Enter a character: ";
 cin >> c;
 cout <<  int(c);
 return 0;
}
```

> ```
> the name of error is ||=== Build: Debug in dsklsfklsjkl (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\dsklsfklsjkl\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
> C:\Users\user\Desktop\dsklsfklsjkl\main.cpp|9|error: invalid cast from type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to type 'int'|
> ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
> ```

Comment: Same question just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508649/ascii-converter-for-numbers

Comment: This look's like a duplicate, but this person is trying to convert a ```string``` to number. Tough decision....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASCII converter The numbers without char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494609/ascii-converter-the-numbers-without-char)

Answer (score 2):

get in char c ,instead of string

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char c;
 cout << "Enter a character: ";
 cin >> c;
 cout <<  int(c);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to convert `std::string` to a number, what you want is probably to use a `char` instead. Your code example would then look like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char c;
 cout << "Enter a character: ";
 cin >> c;
 cout <<  (int)c;
 return 0;
}
```

A character is in C++ a number, since you are wanting the ASCII number I am not assuming that you are looking for any UTF-8 or similar numbers, in which case a single `char` is enough.

You can see a sample of it running here: https://ideone.com/S0fCBL

As input I gave the character `k` the output was the number `107`, which is the ASCII value for the character `k` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

If you really wanted the string to be converted to a number, then you would have to use the [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) functions, but then the number you would convert the string to would be the integer representation of the string, and not the ASCII value of the individual characters in the string. If what you want is to know the ASCII value of the individual characters in the string, you would have to iterate through the characters, and cast them to `int` and print them out individually.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because of the conversion `int(c)`.   The `std::string` type simply does not support a conversion to `int`.

Assuming your implementation uses a character set that is compatible with ASCII, you need to read a single `char` (not a `std::string`, which consists of a set of `char`s).  Converting that `char` to an `int` will then give the result you intend.

If your implementation uses a character set that is not compatible with ASCII (rare in practice, but possible) then you'll need to implement a mapping between characters and their ASCII values.

Comment: When `c` holds any of the characters `'0' ... '9'`, `c - '0'` works for **all** character encodings, not just ASCII. And converting a `char` value to `int` just works.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `char` instead of `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 char c;
 cout << "Enter a character: ";
 cin >> c;
 cout <<  int(c);
 return 0;
}
```