# Converting a Vector of Characters to a Vector of Strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

for the following [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-common-characters/), I need to return a vector of strings, where each element in the vector is of length 1. I have an answer that generates a vector of characters. I think it does what I need, but I'm not sure how to return the result as a vector of strings of length one. See my implementation below. Note, I can't change the return type of the function, it must be a vector of strings. Given that I operate on characters in my solution, I'm not sure how I'd change it.

```
    vector<string> commonChars(vector<string>& A) {
        vector<char> resVec;
        unordered_map<char, int> mapObj;

        for (const auto& str : A) {
            for (const auto& letter : str) {
                mapObj[letter]++;
            }
        }

        int sizeOfInput = A.size();
        for (int i{}; i < A[0].size(); i++) {
            if (!mapObj.count(A[0][i])) continue;
            resVec.insert(resVec.begin(), mapObj[(A[i])] / sizeOfInput, A[i]); 
        }
        return resVec;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a single character to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222572/convert-a-single-character-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
std::vector<char> resVec;
...
std::vector<std::string> returnVec;
returnVec.reserve(resVec.size());
for (char ch : resVec) {
    returnVec.push_back(std::string(1, ch));
    // or: returnVec.emplace_back(1, ch);
}
return returnVec;
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
std::vector<char> resVec;
...
std::vector<std::string> returnVec;
returnVec.reserve(resVec.size());
std::transform(resVec.begin(), resVec.end(), std::back_inserter(returnVec), 
    [](char ch){ return std::string(1, ch); }
);
return returnVec;
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
std::vector<char> resVec;
...
std::vector<std::string> returnVec(resVec.size());
std::transform(resVec.begin(), resVec.end(), returnVec.begin(), 
    [](char ch){ return std::string(1, ch); }
);
return returnVec;
```

That said, you could just eliminate the `std::vector<char>` altogether and just populate the final `std::vector<std::string>` directly from the `std::map` data:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> commonChars(std::vector<std::string>& A) {
    std::vector<std::string> resVec;
    std::unordered_map<char, int> mapObj;

    for (const auto& str : A) {
        for (const auto& letter : str) {
            mapObj[letter]++;
        }
    }

    size_t sizeOfInput = A.size();
    if (sizeOfInput > 0) {
        for (const auto& letter : A[0]) {
            auto iter = mapObj.find(letter);
            if (iter != mapObj.end()) {
                resVec.insert(resVec.begin(), iter->second / sizeOfInput, std::string(1, letter));
            }
        }
    }

    return resVec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<string> ret;
for(char ch: resVec)
    ret.push_back(string(1,ch));
return ret;
```

This is a simple way of converting a `std::vector<char>` to a `std::vector<std::string>`.
If you are interested, you can also take a look at: [Convert a single character to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222572/convert-a-single-character-to-a-string)

In short `string(1,ch)` is what does the actual conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There's a different way to approach the problem. You could count the occurrences of each letter a-z in a vector for each string and loop through each vector, adding the minimum number of times a character occurs in all strings:

```
vector<string> commonChars(vector<string>& A) {
    const int maxTimes=100;
    vector<string> resVec;
    vector<vector<int>> counts;
    counts.reserve(A.size());

    //Count occurrences of letters in each string
    for (const auto& word : A) {
        vector<int> count(26, 0);
        for (const auto letter : word) {
            count[letter-'a']++;
        }
        counts.push_back(count);
    }

    //Add minimum number of times a letter occurs in all strings
    for (int i=0; i<26; ++i)
    {
        int min=maxTimes;
        for (auto &count : counts)
        {
            if (count[i] < min) {
                min = count[i];
            }
        }

        for (int j=0; j<min; ++j) {                 
            resVec.push_back(string(1, i+'a'));
        }
    }

    return resVec;
}
```

Note: `string(1, i+'a')` creates a string of size 1 from a single char (value: i+'a').

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for this.