# C++ Convert char to CString

Tags: c++, c-strings, wchar-t, wchar

before i looked at all similar threads on every forum but i didn't found a solution which works for me.
I'm a very beginner in C++, so please don't be to strict with me.

My Problem is that i want to open a file, and read the characters with a buffers. And then i want to convert them to a CString.

```
CString    buffer;

CString    temp;

...

BYTE buffer[4096] ;

        DWORD dwRead ;

        temp  = _T("");

        do
        {
            dwRead = sourceFile.Read(buffer, 4096) ;

            for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++)
            {
                temp = temp + ((CString) (char)buffer[i]);
            }
        }
```

--> The problem is that the buffer just can be read a s a char. I don't know to convert it to CString. 
I read very much other stackoverflow solutions but found nothing which works for me. Like the MultiByteToWideChar or something... Could somebody help me and can tell me where my fault is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a single character to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222572/convert-a-single-character-to-a-string)

Comment: warning: super nitpick. No you didnt look at **all** similar threads on **every** forum. You can remove that from your question without losing any essential information. Starting your question with this reads as if you dont tell us the truth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As e.g. explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3709f7fe-a7f8-41d2-95e7-92a29329f536/), you can convert the whole buffer into a `CString` in one go, without the inner loop:

```cpp
while ((dwRead = sourceFile.Read(buffer, 4096)) > 0) {
    CString block (buffer, dwRead);
    temp += block;
}
```

The `temp  = _T("");` is unneccessary; a default-constructed `CString` (i.e. one created like `CString temp;`) is automatically an empty string.

If you really need to append a single character, you could just do `temp += someChar;`.